# Yii $this->save() and $this->commit() saves only the last record when used in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I was trying to insert multiple records into my database via a model in Yii. I am passing the data to model from controller using foreach. At first it checks if the field exists in database and if the result is false, inserts into database. However, when inserting, it does not insert the first record, instead it is inserting the record which is passed at the end from controller. But generates an Id as soon as the first data is passed to the controller.

My controller:

```
foreach($user_likes['data'] as $ul){
    $category_id = $categoriesModel->ifCategoryExists($ul['category']);
    if(!$category_id){
      $category_id = $categoriesModel->add($ul['category']);                        
      $categories[$category_id] = $ul['category'];                          
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
public function add($params = '') {
    $transaction = $this->dbConnection->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $this->Category = $params;
        $this->save();
        $transaction->commit();
        echo "{ inserted_id ", $this->Id," },{ inserted_category ",$params," }<br/>";
        return $this->Id;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

When I see the output from echo

```
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Community }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Local business }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Actor/director }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Event planning/event services }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Album }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Magazine }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Internet/software }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Consulting/business services }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Education website }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Author }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Public figure }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Business person }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Public figure }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Community }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Comedian }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Business person }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Public figure }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category News personality }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Political organization }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Computers/technology }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Travel/leisure }
{ inserted_id 17 },{ inserted_category Community }
```

And very strangely, it is inserting

```
Community
```

Comment: may be u need to set $this->isNewRecord=TRUE; AND $this->id = NULL before $this->save(); ?

Comment: This may be off topic, why are you using a transaction in the add function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CActiveRecord` has a state and it starts out as "new" (and uses the "insert" scenario). As soon as you call save() on it, it is no longer new and goes to the "update" scenario. The `CActiveRecord` is not made to insert different records, 1 instance = 1 row.

However if you really want to use the single instance, just reset the thing:

```
$this->Id = NULL;
$this->isNewRecord = TRUE;
```

If you add this right before your `$this->save()`, it should work. 
I do strongly suggest to use the framework as it was meant to be and create new instances.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the same model, with different attributes over and over (see [`CActiveRecord::save()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail) for more info). I'd suggest you use a new instance of `CategoriesModel` per save or set `isNewRecord` to false and unset `id` before saving.

```
public function add($params = '') {
    $transaction = $this->dbConnection->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $this->isNewRecord = false;
        unset($this->Id);
        $this->Category = $params;
        $this->save();
        $transaction->commit();
        echo "{ inserted_id ", $this->Id," },{ inserted_category ",$params," }<br/>";
        return $this->Id;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
}
```